# Input LOG file information into MySQL using Python

Tags: python, mysql, file-io, load

I need to take a linux log file and enter the data into a mysql table, and separate each field into columns.  I have been trying to use the LOAD DATA INFILE command. Only problem is, the data is not delimited and I cannot TERMINATE FIELDS BY '' because the file includes spaces in the log message.  If anyone has any idea please let me know

Example of file:

2011-01-17 10:18:20 User xxxxxx requested backup of xxxxx (xxxxx)

2011-01-17 10:18:29 Stopping current full of xxxxxx, request by backuppc (backoff=)

2011-01-17 10:18:33 User xxxxxx requested backup of xxxxxx (xxxxxx )

2011-01-17 10:18:51 Backup canceled on xxxxxx (received signal=ALRM)

2011-01-17 10:18:52 Started full backup on xxxxxx (pid=xxxxxx , share=xxxxxx$)

2011-01-17 10:24:18 Started full backup on xxxxxx (pid=xxxxxx , share=xxxxxx$)

2011-01-17 11:00:01 Next wakeup is 2011-01-17 12:00:01

2011-01-17 12:00:03 Next wakeup is 2011-01-17 13:00:00

2011-01-17 13:00:01 Next wakeup is 2011-01-17 14:00:00

Answer (score 1):

Pre-format this file. I'm assuming the blank lines in your file are not there (otherwise you can remove them using the commented code). Let's say you're using python:

```
parsed = open("parsed.txt", 'a')                                                                                                                                        
    with open("log.txt") as f:                                                                                                                                              
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        # use if your lines have spaces in between
        # if i % 2 == 0:                                                                                                                                                      
        parsed.write(line.replace(" ",",",2))
```

Giving you a file like:

```
2011-01-17,10:18:20,User xxxxxx requested backup of xxxxx (xxxxx)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
2011-01-17,10:18:52,Started full backup on xxxxxx (pid=xxxxxx , share=xxxxxx$)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
2011-01-17,10:24:18,Started full backup on xxxxxx (pid=xxxxxx , share=xxxxxx$) 
...
```

Now you can:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'parsed.txt' INTO TABLE db.my_table;
```

Comment: I actually decided to go with regex to decipher my file.  Was definitely the long complicated way but it will work out best in the end.  When I initially started looking this is exactly what I wanted, but it turns out regex works well too.  Thanks a bunch man